# Use Dialogflow webhook only to store the chat conversation, call webhook for all indent but use the default text in intents as response

Tags: google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am developing a chatbot using `Google Dialogflow`, integrated with facebook messenger. 
I want to use `Dialogflow webhook` only to store the chat conversation(input parameter), call `webhook` (`Firebase functions - NodeJs`) for all indent but use the default text given inside the intents as response.

Any one tried the same?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

it should be possible. Make sure all intents enable the fulfillment so each incoming message/request is sent to the Webhook.
Your webhook can store data in the database, send an email or generate an event to control the conversation flow: do not set the actual (text) response from your webhook but only define the actual responses in the Intent screen.